# How to update boolean values to 0 if checkboxes are not checked when form is submitted

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, checkbox

I have a game where users information will be inserted into the database every time they finished a survey after the game, so I display these information in a table format in a website, below there is a submit button, so when clicked it will check for checked and unchecked boxes and update the values of the boolean in the database, but currently I was able to check for checked checkboxes but those that are not checked when submitted are not updated in the database.

here is my code to check for uncheck and checkboxes when submitted

```
 <?php

    include_once("dcConnect.php");


    if(!empty( $_POST['myCheckBox'] )){

    $strAllUsernameCombined = implode("','", $_POST['myCheckBox']);
    $sql = "UPDATE dcUsers SET dcChecked = 1 WHERE dcID IN ('{$strAllUsernameCombined}')";

    mysqli_query($link, $sql) or exit("result_message=Error");

    } else {

     $strAllUsernameCombined = implode("','", $_POST['myCheckBox']);
     $sql = "UPDATE dcUsers SET dcChecked = 0 WHERE dcID IN ('{$strAllUsernameCombined}')";

    mysqli_query($link, $sql) or exit("result_message=Error");
    }

    ?>
```

Here is how I display the data from the database

```
 <p>
<form action="default3.php" method="post"</form>
            <?php
    include_once("dcConnect.php");

    $dcData = "SELECT dcChecked, dcID, dcServerName, dcServerOc, dcServerAge, dcServerGender, dcServerMarital, dcServerCode, dcServerPoints FROM dcUsers";

    $result = $link->query($dcData);

    if($result->num_rows >0){
        echo"<table><tr><th>Redeem</th><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Occupation</th><th>Age Group</th><th>Gender</th><th>Marital Status</th><th>Code</th><th>Points</th></tr>";
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "<tr><td></input><input type='checkbox' id='". $row["dcID"] ."' name='myCheckBox[]' value='". $row["dcID"] ."'".(($row["dcChecked"]) ? 'checked="checked"':"")." ></input></td><td>". $row["dcID"] ."</td><td>". $row["dcServerName"] ."</td><td>". $row["dcServerOc"] ."</td><td>". $row["dcServerAge"] ."</td><td>". $row["dcServerGender"] ."</td><td>". $row["dcServerMarital"] ."</td><td>". $row["dcServerCode"] ."</td><td>". $row["dcServerPoints"] ."</td></tr>";





        }
        echo "</table>" ;

        }else{
            echo"no results";

        }




    $link->close();



    ?></p>

          <input type="submit" name="submitter" value="Save">   
        </form>
```

here is the link to my website
http://forstoringdata.com/default.php

Comment: You can use hidden same-named inputs that will register the unchecked boxes. Put them before the checkboxes and if checked, will overwrite the empty values from the hidden fields.

Comment: Or you can contrast two arrays, one from your questions array and one from your answers array and get the difference

Comment: I think `empty( $_POST['myCheckBox'] )` returns true either the check box in checked or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML checkbox after submit will lost value if not checked. you need to add a hidden input **BEFORE** that checkbox

```
<input type='hidden' name='myCheckBox[0]' value='0'>

<input type='checkbox' id='". $row["dcID"] ."' name='myCheckBox[]' value='". $row["dcID"] ."'".(($row["dcChecked"]) ? 'checked="checked"':"")." >
```

However I guess you want default 0 for each unchecked boxes: **After reading your website, this next method is preferred:**

```
<input type='hidden' name='myCheckbox[". $row['dcID'] ."]' value='0'>       
<input type='checkbox' name='myCheckBox[". $row['dcID'] ."]' 
    value='1'". ($row['dcChecked'] ? ' checked' : '') .">
```

And here is the PHP to update MySQL bit:

```
if (isset($_POST['myCheckBox'])) {
    $yes = $no = array();
    foreach ($_POST['myCheckBox'] as $dcID => $dcChecked) {
        if ($dcChecked) {
            $yes[] = $dcID;
        } else {
            $no[]  = $dcID;
        }
    }
    if (count($yes)) {
        $sql = 'UPDATE dcUsers SET dcChecked = 1 WHERE dcID IN ('. implode(',', $yes) .')';
        mysqli_query($link, $sql) or exit("result_message=Error");
    }
    if (count($no)) {
        $sql = 'UPDATE dcUsers SET dcChecked = 0 WHERE dcID IN ('. implode(',', $no) .')';
        echo $sql; //delete this line after debugging
        mysqli_query($link, $sql) or exit("result_message=Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is there anything  I should change for the mysql statements?

Comment: Hey, I got this error after trying out the code Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /home/forsto5/public_html/default3.php

Comment: the boolean still does not change to 0 when the checkboxes are unchecked.. :((  but it changed to 1 when checked.

Comment: My Answer is updated. did you try again using my new updated answer above?

Comment: yea.., along with the hidden checkbox

Comment: I have deleted one line above this: if (count($no)) {

Comment: You need debug your code by yourself. I have updated above as one example of debugging

Comment: it did not show anything on the web, but when i added echo $sql; for if (count($yes)) {} it showed up the sql statement, but when added for  if (count($no)) {} nothing came up

Comment: OHHH, I have found the problem!!!  your input type hidden name had a lower case b haha XDD